# Working with data from http response in Angular

Tags: angular

I've created this `HttpService` which leverages the `HttpClient`. In the service i have 1 method called `getUserId()` that is making a http request to a mock api. In the response I wan't to grab the `userId` property and have the `getUserId()` return the `userId`.

The idea is to be able to get the `userId` in a component by creating an instance of the `HttpService` and call `getUserId()` method. I don't know if this is the right approach but the purpose of the httpservice is to handle all http requests and by creating an instance of it in a component i can access all it's functions depending on what data i need. I am completely new at Angular.

How do i make it so that `getUserId()` returns the `userId` property of the http response?

**httpService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

interface IuserData{
  userId: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUserId(){  
    return this.http.get<IuserData>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").subscribe(data => {
      console.log('User ID: ' + data.userId)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: My issue is that i need getUserId() to return data.userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have `subscribe`d to `this.http.get` in your service. Instead you should have done that in your Component.

Also, instead of passing the whole TODO object, you'll have to `map` it to just return an object with a `userId` key in it so that it serves your purpose of the supplying the Type `T` to the `get` method of `HttpClient`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface UserId {
  userId: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUserId(){  
    return this.http.get<UserId>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .pipe(
        map(todo => ({ userId: todo.userId }))
      );
  }
}
```

Now in your Component:

```
constructor(private http: HttpService) { }
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.getUserId()
    .subscribe(userId => console.log(userId));
}
```

**Side Note:** Angular and TypeScript Styleguide doesn't really recommend prefixing `I` before `interface` names. So I've fixed the name for you.

Comment: I see, thanks for an informative answer. I'm used to .NET, my bad about the interface prefix. Is there a way to access userId outside the Observable. I mean can i assign the userId to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Just inject your service in the component constructor (privately) and call your method then wherever you want:

```
constructor(private httpService HttpService) {
    this.httpService.getUserId();
  }
```

- Here your method will be called within the **constructor**, else you can call it in a **different method** if you want since your service is well injected in the component's constructor.
- Do not forget to **import the service** in the component's file
- **It is better to subscribe in the component's side not in the service's one**
- The component and the service **should be visible to each other** by default (within the same `NgModule` parameters for exemple)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your service just to return the `observable` and **`subscribe`** in your component as follows,

**Service**

```
 getUserId(){  
    return this.http.get<IuserData>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  }
```

**and in component,**

```
 this.http.getUserId().subscribe(userId => console.log(userId));
```